# Sort array by value and alphabet React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I get an array from firebase, it is now sorted alphabetically. If an object contains 'routes' then it will get the text 'Bekijk' button otherwise the text 'coming soon' button, what I would like is that the objects with the name 'Bekijk' are displayed first and then the other objects alphabetically order, does anyone know if that is possible?

This is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ImageBackground, StatusBar, ScrollView, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { Header, Icon,Button,Rating, AirbnbRating  } from 'react-native-elements';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';


class routeScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      goverments: [],
    }
}

  getGovermentData = () => {
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('Goverments');
    ref.on('value' , snapshot =>{
        var state = snapshot.val();
        this.setState({
          goverments: state,
        })
        console.log(state);
      })

  }

    componentWillMount(){
      this.getGovermentData(); 
    }



    render() {
      const width = {
       width: (Dimensions.get('window').width / 2),
      };
      return (
        <ScrollView>

          {
            this.state.goverments.sort(function(a, b) {
              if(a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
              if(a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
              return 0;
             }).map((item, i) => (
              <View style={[styles.cards, { backgroundColor: (i % 2  == 0) ? '#D1A96E' : '#A58657'  }]}>
              <View style={styles.leftcolum}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{item.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.undertitle}>4km - 5km - 7km</Text>
                <Image source={require('./assets/images/stars.png')} style={styles.stars}/>

                <Button buttonStyle={{
                          backgroundColor: item.routes ? "#3F494B" : "#018786",
                          marginTop: 40,
                          borderRadius: 50,
                      }} title={item.routes ? "Bekijk" : "Coming soon"}
                      onPress={() => item.routes ? this.props.navigation.navigate('Location', {govermentData: item}) : '#'}
                      />

              </View>
              <View style={styles.rightcolum}>
                <Image source={{uri: item.logoUrl}} style={{width: 150, height: 68}}/>
              </View>

            </View>
          ))
        }
    </ScrollView>


      );
    }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    cards:{
      backgroundColor: '#D1A96E',
      borderRadius: 10,
      marginTop: 20,
      marginRight: 10,
      marginLeft: 10,
      paddingLeft: 20,
      paddingRight: 20,
      paddingTop: 20,
      paddingBottom: 20,
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      alignItems: 'flex-start'
    },
    stars:{
      marginTop: 10,
    },
    leftcolum:{
      width: '50%',
    },
    rightcolum:{
      width: '50%',
      paddingTop:30,
      paddingLeft:10,
    },
    title:{
      fontSize: 17,
      color: '#fff',
      marginTop: 5,
      fontWeight: '800',
    },
    undertitle:{
      fontSize: 12,
      color: '#fff',
      fontWeight: '200',
    },
    button:{
      backgroundColor: '#3F494B',
      borderRadius: 22,
      marginTop: 20,
    },
    valkenburg:{
      backgroundColor: '#A58657',
    },
    gulpen:{
      backgroundColor: '#EBC285',
    },
    logoValkenburg:{
      width: '50%',
      paddingTop:10,
      paddingLeft:10,
    },
    logoGulpen:{
      width: '50%',
      paddingTop:30,
      paddingLeft:10,
    }

  });

  export default routeScreen;
```

Structure of array:
[image]

what I would like:
now the array is shown in alphabetical order, that is good, I would only like to show object [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWT1n.png) of Goverments at the top because it contains the value routes, with the others the value routes being empty. so if it is filled, it must show it at the top

Comment: i updated the question, hope you can help m further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Goverments = [
  {
    name: 'Valkenburg',
  },
  {
    name: 'Eijsden-Margeaten',
  },
  {
    name: 'Gulpen',
    routes: [],
  },
];
const SortedGoverments = Goverments.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.routes) return -1; // new check
  if(b.routes) return 1; // new check
  if(a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
  if(a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
  return 0;
});

console.log("Goverments : ", Goverments);
console.log("SortedGoverments : ", SortedGoverments);
```